# How to define an array of objects

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, eslint

Using vue 3, typescript and eslint

I have the following code:

```
...
data() {
  return {
    blah: '',
    blah2: []
    ...
```

and in the methods object I have:

```
methods: {
  addEntry() :void {
    this.blah2.push({s:'whatever',b:false});
  }
  ...
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Argument of type '{ s: string; b: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

I've tried the following, none of which work:

```
blah2: any[] = []

blah2: Array<{ s: string, b: Boolean }> = Array()

blah2: Array<{ s: string, b: Boolean }>[] = []

blah2: { s: string, b: Boolean } = []

blah2: { s: string, b: Boolean }[] = []

blah2: any[{ s: string, b: Boolean }] = []
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Note: If I hardcode some initial data like so:

```
...
data() {
  return {
    blah: '',
    blah2: [
      {s:'whatever',b:false}
    ]
    ...
```

then it has no problem, so, I guess, it is working the declaration out from the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the return type of the function
See example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwIZVQCgJQC5EDeARgDaoAW+AzlAE4xgDmANIqRQEz4GJXV0MWbfEThwSAU1RIAvgG0AujMIAoRIloSoIWkgJr1h9pUQByU8wOG2Zcl0SKDMtc5UQENRFAmeAvCnQsbBVvGgA6Yw4wgAcQKnJMAj5TAHdydAkANwlaCyJcYFQSKgkZbABuFSA)

Comment: Good grief. Would have been here all day trying to figure that out.  Cheers NirG